Conceptual explanation of a Gauss's Law result
Suppose you have a spherical-shell of radius $r$ (centered at the origin) and charge $a$. Suppose you have another spherical shell that contains the previous shell with radius R (centered at the origin) and charge $-a$, where R > r strictly.
Now suppose you are looking to find the magnitude of the electric field experienced at some  distance from the origin D, where D > R > r. It may be shown simply with Gauss's Law that
$$ \Phi = \frac{Q_{\text{enc}}}{\varepsilon_0} \implies \frac{q + (-q)}{\varepsilon_0} = 0 \implies E(D) = 0$$
Conceptually this is difficult for me to grasp however. If you imagine field lines for example, at any point outside the larger shell, there is a field line pointing directly toward the origin. Any field line emitted by the inner sphere is 'absorbed' by the inner side of the outer shell, and all there is on the outside are field lines pointing inward. I may naively think that this implies $E(D) \neq 0$, although this certainly cannot be the case because of Gauss's Law and I cannot picture why.
Any help regarding a conceptual explanation of this result is greatly appreciated.

at any point outside the larger shell, there is a field line pointing directly toward the origin. Why? Electric field is electric force per test charge, but any test charge outside the two-shell object won't feel a thing because the object is charge neutral.

I mean you could get intuition for perfectly spherically symmetric objects, That is by taking your previous understanding of coloumb's equation for electric field, we can derive gauss law using Solid angles

If, following Coulomb's law, you consider the field lines of the charge of the inner and outer shell separately, you see the field lines (their electric fields) also outside the outer shell with radius R. But these electric fields have equal strengths with opposite directions and thus compensate each other to exactly zero. Thus there is no electric field outside radius R and thus there are no field lines confirming Gauss' law.

This makes a lot of sense, thank you. I do not know why I assumed field lines from the inner shell would not permeate through the outer shell.
